# How to use helm value in value?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to use helm value in value, for example:

```
db:
  addr: acid-keycloak-db
  user: kcadmin
  secret: {{ user }}.{{ addr }}.credentials.postgresql.acid.zalan.do
```

the output should be:

```
db:
  addr: acid-keycloak-db
  user: kcadmin
  secret: kcadmin.acid-keycloak-db.credentials.postgresql.acid.zalan.do
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

values.yaml

```
db:
  addr: acid-keycloak-db
  user: kcadmin
  secret: "{{ .Values.db.user }}.{{ .Values.db.addr }}.credentials.postgresql.acid.zalan.do"
```

In .yaml file where the secret will be used

```
{{tpl .Values.db.secret . }}
```